# Voltage gain expression of this circuit

Tags: transistors, circuit-analysis, amplifier

After transforming this circuit into its equivalent in small signals, im trying to find the expression of \$ A_v = \frac{v_0}{v_i} \$ [image]

[image]

Here is my sketch of work : \$ v_0 = g_m V_{gs_2} \cdot (R_L || R_{S_2}) \$ and \$v_i = \frac{(R_1 || R_2) + R_{S_i}}{(R_1 || R_2)} V_{gs_1} \$ is this valid?

Comment: Show us the gain expression. Because you did not show us anything useful.

Comment: @G36 but are the expressions of v_i and v_0 correct ?

Comment: They are correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This two-stage NMOS amplifier contains two amplifiers connected in series. The first one is CS (common Source). The second stage is a voltage follower (common drain).

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fBu51d.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Between the Vin and the first NMOS gate we have a voltage divider with a gain equal to:
$$\frac{V_{G1}}{V_{IN}} = \frac{R_{IN}}{R_i + R_{IN}}$$

Next, we have a CS amplifier. The voltage gain for this stage is:

$$V_{D1} = -I_{D1} R_{D1} = -g_{m1} V_{G1} R_{D2}$$

And voltage at the gate is \$V_{G1}\$

Therefore:
$$\frac{V_{D1}}{V_{G1}} = \frac{-g_{m1} V_{G1} R_{D2}}{V_{G1}} = -g_{m1}R_{D1} = -\frac{R_{D1}}{\frac{1}{g_{m1}}}$$

Next, we have to deal with the voltage follower stage.

The voltage gain of this stage can be found like this:

$$V_{OUT} = I_{S2}*(R_{S_2}||R_L) = g_{m2}*v_{gs2}*(R_{S_2}||R_L) $$

The voltage at the gate is:

$$V_{D1} = v_{gs2} + I_{S_2}*(R_{S_2}||R_L) = v_{gs2} + g_{m2}*v_{gs2}*(R_{S_2}||R_L)  $$
$$=v_{gs2}\left(1 +  g_{m2}(R_{S_2}||R_L)\right)$$

So the voltage gain of this stage is:

$$\frac{V_{OUT}}{V_{D1}} = \frac{v_{gs2}\: g_{m2}\: (R_{S_2}||R_L)}{v_{gs2}\left(1 +  g_{m2}(R_{S_2}||R_L)\right)} = \frac{g_{m2}(R_{S_2}||R_L)}{1 +  g_{m2}(R_{S_2}||R_L)}=$$
$$=\frac{R_{S_2}||R_L}{\frac{1}{g_{m2}} + R_{S_2}||R_L}$$

And finally, we have all the information needed to find the overall amplifier voltage gain.

$$\frac{V_{OUT}}{V_{IN}} = - \frac{R_{IN}}{R_i + R_{IN}} \times \frac{R_{D_1}}{\frac{1}{g_{m_1}}} \times\frac{R_{S_2}||R_L}{\frac{1}{g_{m_2}} + R_{S_2}||R_L} $$

This is a "standard procedure" for finding the voltage gain in multistage amplifiers. Go through it very carefully and try to understand it.